Calling SOAP API using java
Hi I'm trying to call a SOAP Api from java, which tries to connect using tenantid, username, password, roles.
package com.virima.test;

import javax.xml.soap.*;

public class SOAPClient {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String soapEndpointUrl = "https://virimadev.trysaasit.com/ServiceAPI/FRSHEATIntegration.asmx";
        String soapAction = "SaaS.Services/Connect";

        callSoapWebService(soapEndpointUrl, soapAction);
    }

    private static void createSoapEnvelope(SOAPMessage soapMessage) throws SOAPException {
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        String myNamespace = "ns";
        String myNamespaceURI = "SaaS.Services";

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(myNamespace, myNamespaceURI);

        // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("tenantId", myNamespace);
        soapBodyElem.addTextNode("virimadev.trysaasit.com");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBody.addChildElement("userName", myNamespace);
        soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("Alan.Taylor");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBody.addChildElement("userName", myNamespace);
        soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("password");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem3 = soapBody.addChildElement("role", myNamespace);
        soapBodyElem3.addTextNode("Admin");
    }

    private static void callSoapWebService(String soapEndpointUrl, String soapAction) {
        try {
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

            // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(soapAction), soapEndpointUrl);

            // Print the SOAP Response
            System.out.println("Response SOAP Message:");
            soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);
            System.out.println();

            soapConnection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("\nError occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server!\nMake sure you have the correct endpoint URL and SOAPAction!\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest(String soapAction) throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

        createSoapEnvelope(soapMessage);

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", soapAction);

        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        /* Print the request message, just for debugging purposes */
        System.out.println("Request SOAP Message:");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println("\n");

        return soapMessage;
    }

}

But I'm getting the following error
Request SOAP Message:
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="SaaS.Services"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns:tenantId>https://virimadev.trysaasit.com</ns:tenantId><ns:userName>Alan.Taylor</ns:userName><ns:userName>Manage</ns:userName><ns:role>Admin</ns:role></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

I'm geting response with following error
Unhandled system exception: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---&amp;amp;gt; System.ArgumentNullException: CacheKey constructor tenantId-argument cannot be null-or-empty.
Parameter name: tenantId

I'm passing tenantId, but still it is saying parameter tenantId cant be null. Is there anything I'm missing.

Are you sure you have correct myNamespaceURI? "SaaS.Services" doesn't look like URI at all.

<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="SaaS.Services">
this is what targetNameSpace I found from the WSDL url. If this is not the myNamespaceURI, where can I find it?

Look like you have to ask help from people maintaining that service.

One thing you can try is to replace soapBody.addChildElement("tenantId", myNamespace) with soapBody.addAttribute("tenantId", myNamespace)

Also having XSD for it may help.

I tried changing to addAttribute(Name, String). What name should be passed here as an arg? I tried this soapBody.addAttribute("tenantId", myNamespace), but its throwing error for me.
Also without XSD can I call these api directly?

What error do you get? XSD will help you to understand what do they expect.

I'm getting change the addAttribute to setAttribute. If I use set attribute I'm getting ( Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to SOAPElement) error.
